# recognizing small objects in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on a project of 3D calibration with OpenCV using the Chessboard. The calibration works fine, but I want to recognize objects in the chessboard that are also black  and should be different from one another, as in the image below.  I don't know how to do this. Which OpenCV functions would be helpful to achieve this goal?

[image: .]

after the suggestion of @Aurelius I tried  to use the cv::matchTemplate, it works fine when I run it in the first but when I run it on a capture the result is totally wrong see the next image

[image: Capture]
any idea how this could be solve

Comment: if you have a template of how the figures you want to detect are, use SIFT or SURF feature detection.

Comment: I've already tried with the sample code of opencv it doesn't recognizes only my object ??

Comment: So I just implemented `canny` on this image and used `findLines`. Sinece this is a really good image, you can easily get lines. Now, based upon length of the line segments, you can remove big lines from the image and you would be left with only the objects that you want. Now, you can train haar classifiers or simply use templates to recognize the objects. If the objects are simple enough, you could also use hough transform if your shapes are simple enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what the shapes will look like ahead of time and your chessboard image is taken straight-on like your example, it looks like a perfect case for [`cv::matchTemplate()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?#matchTemplate). The code below searches the image for areas which best match the template images.

```
cv::Mat chessboard = cv::imread(path_to_image);
cv::Mat template1 = cv::imread(temp1_path);
cv::Mat template2 = cv::imread(temp2_path);

cv::Mat cross_corr;
cv::Point maxloc;

// Find the first template
cv::matchTemplate(chessboard, template1, cross_corr, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
cv::minMaxLoc(cross_corr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &maxloc);    //Only want location of maximum response
cv::Rect t1rect(maxloc,template1.size());

//Find the second template
cv::matchTemplate(chessboard, template2, cross_corr, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
cv::minMaxLoc(cross_corr, nullptr,nullptr,nullptr,&maxloc);
cv::Rect t2rect(maxloc, template2.size());

//Draw the results
cv::rectangle(chessboard, t1rect, cv::Scalar(255,0,0), 3);
cv::rectangle(chessboard, t2rect, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 3);
cv::imshow("detection", chessboard);
```

Using these templates:
[image: Template 1]
[image: Template 2]
The code above results in the following output:

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for your help, indeed it works, but when I try to run the program on frame Capture the result is completely wrong !! see my edit

Comment: @Engine As the next answer says, template matching is not rotation invariant. Another option I see is to use Template Matching, but to have 10-15 images of the same piece as a template. find all of them and compare the matches. The most similar one would be the correct match and you found the object.

Comment: @Engine You might consider unwarping your capture image (possibly via `cv::findHomography()` and `cv::warpPerspective()`) to get an image where the chessboard squares appear without any perspective distortion. You could then try template matching with four images for each template (one for every 90-degree rotation). It's not very elegant, but it might work. However, finding textureless shapes *in arbitrary orientations* is **not** a simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

Template matching is not rotation invariant. Do you rotate the chessboard image before template matching (this is what calibration is needed for).